# azure vms aren't communicating anymore

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

This is very weird. I have 2 vms: a Windows 2012 SP1 VM (with AD role) and a Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. They share the same vnet, that is 192.168.99.x (same region, same resource group, same vnet, same subaddr segment).

Until yesterday, they were talking to each other through it's VIP addr (192.168.99.4 and 192.168.99.5). Then, I shut down the Ubuntu VM (went to the deallocated status, I think) and created another Ubuntu VM to test some things.

But today, I started back the original Ubuntu VM, and suddenly they stopped talking to each other! I have reviewed all settings but nothing came to my help.

I'm testing connectivity this way: while sshing the Ubuntu box, i wget a site that exists in Windows 2012 Server. The site is online, no specific ip binding, I can browse it through windows console using vip ip.

Since my knowledge of Azure and it's powershell scripts is limited, I need some direction where to look!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was trying to avoid this, but couldn't wait: I removed the Ubuntu VM from the subnet (adding to another), restarted, returned to the same subnet, restarted again, and voila! The communication was restored. It's odd that you have to do this kind of nonsense movement as a last resource...

Comment: actually, there was probably something wrong with your network settings that were preventing the communication. When you redeploy the VM, the network settings reset. Same happens when you change the size of the VM, it basically deallocates from the current cluster and deploys to a new one, hence, resetting the network.